# wxpython: How do I make my window full-sized when I make the window?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm new to wxpython and I want to know how to make my window full sized. How would I do this? Here's my code:

```
import wx


app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/12/wxpython-making-your-frame-maximize-or-full-screen/

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I meant to say maximize it not make it cover my entire computer screen. But the code in there worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import wx


app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World")
frame.Maximize(True)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. This is my first question on stackoverflow.